# I think I broke windows

Tags: windows-10, sandbox

I was on Win10 Home and as I admired the new sandbox abilities I tried to activate it on my Home version by following Darkmodded [here](https://www.deskmodder.de/blog/2019/04/20/windows-10-home-windows-sandbox-installieren-und-nutzen/).

His method didn't work, it gave me an error saying "connection to the sandbox was lost"

So I BOUGHT a genuine Windows Pro version and upgraded as I really needed the sandbox, but guess what? The problem presists, can't enable the sandbox no matter what.

PS: Hyper-V is enabled in both the system and BIOS.

Comment: Since Hyper-V is not a feature of BIOS, I think you mean, you enable hardware virtualization within BIOS (Hyper-V simply requires it).

Comment: Hopefully, before you upgraded to Windows 10 Professional, you uninstalled Sandbox, if you have not actually attempted that you should.  Of course, it is difficult to determine what you actually did, since the instructions are not in English.  Of course, I know what you did, but only because of something I discovered on another website, which I already know didn't work.  Which is the reason you should always check with us before you start using unsupported methods to enable features that don't work on other editions of Windows.

Comment: Thanks for your time, really appreciate it. What I did was as following: 1. [On Home] Installed the said method, didn't work. 2. Didn't uninstall it, and upgraded to Pro for it to hopefully work. 3. Didn't work either way. So I guess a fresh Windows installation will sort things out?